# The cube does not rotate on mouse click

Tags: unity-game-engine

This code works and rotates a cube,

```
public float Speed;

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

but this does't work :
I'm trying to rotate left on left mouse click,
and rotate right on right mouse click. Only clicking for a moment, not holding down. :

```
public float Speed;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // left mouse clicked.
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) // right mouse clicked.
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }        
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Note :
I have attached the script,
its speed is 250.

Thank you.

Comment: You do realise the bajillion clicks you need to do in your code to rotate it as you only rotate it for 1 frame each click and with deltatime that number is like 1 atom?

Comment: what is your speed?

Comment: also check for when it is held down and not clicked

Comment: @Jadon Wolfgang its 250.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend has fixed the problem :

```
public class Rotator2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool Forward = true;
    public float Speed;

    void Start()
    {
        Forward = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Forward = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Forward = false;
        }

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, (Forward ? 1 : -1) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` instead of `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`. For your code it rotates for each click, but if the speed is not big enough you wont even notice. With `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` the cube will rotate **while** button is pressed.

Comment: Check that the class is monobehaviour, that it is attached to the cube gameObject, and that the speed is not 0 in the editor, and that it is high enough. 100 for example

Comment: The speed is 250. Yes I have attached.

Comment: check with other input key instead of the mouse. Happens the same?

Comment: Also click should take place within the game window

Answer (score 0):

`GetMouseButtonDown` is executed one time during the frame in which the button was pressed down. The same goes for `GetMouseButtonUp` and you are looking for `Input.GetMouseButton` which returns true for each frame when the button is pressed.

So your code is executed every time you press the button, then you need to release it to work again.

```
public float Speed;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) // sol mouse tıklandı
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1)) // sağ mouse tıkladı
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }        
}
```

To debug such issues yourselves you could place `Debug.Log("Works?")` to check if your code is reaching given point or attach debugger

Comment: Check if your speed is not 0. Because it works for me! Also, check if you are not using new Unity Input system

Comment: The speed is 250. I don't know what the new Unity Input system is. I installed the version 2020.1.3f1

Answer (score 0):

The best ways would be to *or* check for a click and then run a coroutine for a couple of seconds/a for loop with a fixed amount of turns, *or* check if the mouse button is held down.

Comment: i will test out the code for you and come back. because it should work. maybe try restarting your editor.

Comment: Thank you so much but you don't have to spare time, because I'm going to ask my Unity expert friend.

Comment: Yeah ofc, we are all here to learn so i will probably also learn from this experience!!!

Comment: I understood, okey.

Comment: Have you reset the component on your object?

Comment: and is it attached?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i have found to things:

```
public float Speed;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

this will rotate the object with a fixed amount. when you push the mouse button 0 or 1.

```
    public float Speed;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

this will (as suspected) rotate the object while the mouse buttons are pressed down.

Comment: are you SURE that you have added the script on the object and it is active?

Comment: Asker doesnt want to need to hold the button down, so may actually only be holding the button down for one or two frames

Comment: Yes I planned to click only once for left and right click.

Comment: then use OnMouseButtonDown(). but did you save it, did you reset it,did you remove and readd it? try those things plzz.

Comment: @Jadon Wolfgang I attached when I was using only rotate code. And did not do something new after that. It was working.

Comment: Okey I will try them and notify here.

Answer (score 0):

Same code with using enum, rather than using bool :

```
enum Direction
{
    None,
    Forward,
    Backward
}

public class Rotator2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    Direction Direction = Direction.Forward;
    public float Speed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Direction = Direction.Forward;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Direction = Direction.Backward;
        }
        
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, (Direction== Direction.Forward ? 1 : -1 ) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);            
    }
}
```